# Deleting all dll-extensions

Tags: c#

Made a program with 20,000 line of code.
Only problem I have from finishing it to being published is
I'm trying to get everything ending in extension .DLL will be deleted in the folder. 
OR prevent the application from opening when it detects a .DLL EXTENSION anywhere within
that executable.

Now I have a code which does work:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curFile = "FILENAME.dll";
    if (File.Exists(curFile))
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

The only problem i have with that code is the file name. Anybody could just rename the file name to a specific name besides that one and still get in with a modified lib to disect my code
this also works because i do not need to specify the location of path or directory it does it for me.
I need to pretty much stop any types of those specific extensions from being in the same path as that executable instead of it seeing the name "FILENAME.DLL" just ".DLL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all DLL in some directory use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

You can use [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) for current application directory.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var allDlls = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.dll");
    if (allDlls.Any())
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't be what I'm looking for. ("path_to_some_directory", "*.dll");
Won't work because someone else doesn't have the same specified path. This is being published

Comment: @CrazyLeak `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`?

Comment: No that doesn't work if i do var allDlls = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, "*.dll");
or
var allDlls = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory("path_to_some_directory", "*.dll");
I get an error syntax

Comment: @CrazyLeak I really, don't understand clear what do you want

Comment: @CrazyLeak because Directory.GetCurrentDirectory is a method :) `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: If the user puts my executable in any location he wishes to.
And they're is a .dll extension detected in that same path the program will be forced to quit and not load. To prevent dicection

Comment: @CrazyLeak Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() must help

Comment: Could you please put it in full form.